# Spring data projection

Tags: java, spring-data, jpql, spring-projections

My project has entity PostEntity with couple of many-to-many relationships, the goal is to retrieve simple projection with names of PostEntity associated entities:

```
@Query(" select template.name as templates, resource.name as resources from TemplateEntity template, "
        + "ResourceEntity "
        + "resource "
        + " left join template.posts as tposts "
        + " left join resource.posts as rposts "
        + " where (template.workspace =:workspace and tposts.uuid =:uuid) "
        + " or( resource.workspace =:workspace and rposts.uuid =:uuid) ")
PostDependencyModel findDependencies(@Param(value = "workspace") WorkspaceEntity workspace,
        @Param(value = "uuid") String uuid);
```

The projection:

```
public interface PostDependencyModel {

    Set<String> getTemplates();

    Set<String> getResources();
}
```

The problem: when the query founds at least one resource and template, it returns projection, otherwise it returns null. The question: how to return empty collection this way?

Comment: Change return type to List<PostDependencyModel>

Comment: It works. By the way, is return type List related to many-to-many relationship? Thought it should be unique result here.

Comment: No, this is just mapping the rows in the result set returned by the query to a collection of PostDependencyModesl. doesn't matter if there are none, one or many rows